# listen to DOM change with MutationObserver doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers

I want to log something when my stackoverflow question have a reply. I pasted my below code into the console.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
   mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      if(mutation) { alert('replied!'); console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0]) }
   })
})

var inboxNdoe = document.querySelector('.inbox-button-item')
observer.observe(inboxNdoe, {childList: true})
```

but someone replied my question, it doesn't show the alert, am I missing something?

Comment: The mutation occurred inside the DOM tree. Try adding `subtree:true` option.

Comment: @wOxxOm tried..

Comment: Add `attributes: true` and `characterData: true` as well.

Comment: what is that for? `substree:true` is already working.